# Is $h=f-g$ smooth?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $$f(t)=\left(1-4\left(t-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2,0\right)$$
and $$g(t)=\left(\frac{1}{2},\left(t-\frac{1}{4}\right)^2\right).$$
are $f,g$ and $h$ smooth ? We define $h=f-g$.

I said that $f'(1/2)=g'(1/4)=0$ and thus $f$ and $g$ are not regular, then not smooth. For $h$ I have that $$h'(t)=\left(-8\left(t-\frac{1}{2}\right),-2\left(t-\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)\neq 0.$$
Then $g$ is regular. But since $h'''(t)=0$, the function $h$ is not smooth, no ? My solutions said that since it's regular, it's smooth. It not correct, no ?

Comment: Is there something missing in your definitions? Perhaps you meant $f(t) = \max(..., 0)$ or something similar? And what is $h$?

Comment: $h$ is $f-g$. An no, $f$ is as I defined. Why it looks strange ? @MartinR

Comment: So you are talking about vector-valued functions $f,g, h: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R^2$? What is the problem? Each component is a polynomial and very smooth.

Comment: my problème is why the fact that $h'(t)\neq 0$ tel us that it's smooth ? and why $f$ is not smooth ? (because it's also polynomial), but in the solution it's written that the fact that $f$ is not regular implies it's not smooth. @MartinR

Comment: Define smooth please.

Comment: @zhw: smotth is $\mathcal C^\infty $.

Comment: Well then those maps are obviously smooth.